# Computing the derivatives of $e^{-rT} \int_{K}^{+\infty} (s - k)\Phi(T, s) \, \mathrm{d}s$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> $$ c(T,K) = e^{-rT} \int_{K}^{+\infty} (s - K)\Phi(T, s) \, \mathrm{d}s $$
>
> Then
>
> $$ \frac{\partial c(T,K)}{\partial K} = -e^{-rT} \int_{K}^{+\infty} \Phi(T, s) \, \mathrm{d}s \qquad \text{and} \qquad \frac{\partial^2 c(T,K)}{\partial K^2} = e^{-rT} \Phi(T, K). $$

I am having problem with the derivation from the top integral to the bottom 2 derivatives. Can someone please show me step by step of the derivation, **Especially** for the derivation of the 2<sup>nd</sup> derivative?

Your help would be very much appreciated!

This is an extract from the Dupire Formula.

$$ c(T,K) = e^{-rT} \int_{K}^{+\infty} (s - K)\Phi(T, s) \, \mathrm{d}s $$

Can someone please share with me the steps to get to this:

$$ \frac{\partial c(T,K)}{\partial K} = -e^{-rT} \int_{K}^{+\infty} \Phi(T, s) \, \mathrm{d}s \qquad \text{and} \qquad \frac{\partial^2 c(T,K)}{\partial K^2} = e^{-rT} \Phi(T, K). $$

---

[Reference: Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G87Dr.jpg)

Comment: https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php you can use this to easily edit your question for better display

Comment: I edited your question a bit. Hope this is to your liking.

Comment: Thank you for your @SangchulLee help.

Comment: @BJKShah Thank you.

Comment: @SangchulLee Hi would you please tell me how do you make the attached screenshot directly visible. When I uploaded it, it appeared as a link on the website.

Comment: @Bryant, If you upload an image, you can check the number and URL of the image at the bottom of the body. Then the markup `![description][image no.]` can be used to insert it. (The description is normally not visible from the rendered text, although it helps improve the accessibility.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x), g(x), h(t,x)$ be nice functions. Then the following formula is well-known under the name [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule):

\begin{align*}
&\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \int_{f(x)}^{g(x)} h(t, x) \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&\qquad = g'(x)h(g(x),x) - f'(x)h(f(x),x) + \int_{f(x)}^{g(x)} \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(t, x) \, \mathrm{d}t.
\end{align*}

Using this, it follows that

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial c(K)}{\partial K}
&= - \left[ e^{-rT}(s-K)\Phi(T, s) \right]_{s=K} + \int_{K}^{+\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial K} e^{-rT}(s-K)\Phi(T, s) \, \mathrm{d}s\\
&= -\int_{K}^{+\infty} e^{-rT}\Phi(T, s) \, \mathrm{d}s.
\end{align*}

Differentiating this again with respect to $K$ is much easier in view of FToC, and we get

$$ \frac{\partial^2 c(K)}{\partial K^2} = -\frac{\partial}{\partial K}\int_{K}^{+\infty} e^{-rT}\Phi(T, s) \, \mathrm{d}s = e^{-rT} \Phi(T, K). $$

Comment: I finally understand your approach, thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

$$
c(T,K) = e^{-rT} \int_{\color{red}{K}}^{+\infty} (s - \color{blue}{K})\Phi(T, s) \, ds
$$
We see $K$ here twice.  So the partial derivative $\partial/\partial K$ is done with two terms.
Think of
$$
b(T,\color{red}{A},\color{blue}{B}) = e^{-rT} \int_{\color{red}{A}}^{+\infty} (s - \color{blue}{B})\Phi(T, s) \, ds
$$
and then
$$
\frac{\partial c}{\partial K} = \frac{\partial b}{\partial A}\;\frac{\partial A}{\partial K} + \frac{\partial b}{\partial B}\;\frac{\partial B}{\partial K}
$$
where $A=K, B=K$. Now
$$
\frac{\partial b}{\partial A} = -e^{-rT}(A-B)\Phi(T,A)
\\
\frac{\partial b}{\partial B} = -e^{-rT} \int_{A}^{+\infty} \Phi(T, s) \, ds
$$
and $\partial A/\partial K = 1$, $\partial B/\partial K = 1$. Thus 
$$
\frac{\partial c}{\partial K} =
-e^{-rT}(K-K)\Phi(T,A)
-e^{-rT} \int_{K}^{+\infty} \Phi(T, s) \, ds
=-e^{-rT} \int_{K}^{+\infty} \Phi(T, s) \, ds
$$
as claimed.

Comment: This is both concise and more informative then my answer. (+1)

Comment: Thank you, I understand now, how about the second derivative? Is it merely a removal of the integration?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably some way to solve this by a clever substitution, but I haven't seen it yet. I only see how to directly apply the definition of a derivative.

You have $c(T,K)$ defined by
$$ c(T,K) = e^{−rT} \int_K^\infty (s − K)\Phi(T,s)\,ds.$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
 c(T,K+h) &= e^{−rT} \int_{K+h}^\infty (s − (K+h))\Phi(T,s)\,ds \\
&= e^{−rT} \int_{K+h}^\infty (s − K)\Phi(T,s)\,ds
 - h e^{−rT} \int_{K+h}^\infty \Phi(T,s)\,ds \\
&= e^{−rT} \int_K^\infty (s − K)\Phi(T,s)\,ds \\
 &\qquad - e^{−rT} \int_K^{K+h} (s − K)\Phi(T,s)\,ds \\
 &\qquad - h e^{−rT} \int_{K+h}^\infty \Phi(T,s)\,ds,
\end{align}
so
\begin{align}
\frac{c(T,K+h) - c(T,K)}h &= \frac1h\left(
 - e^{−rT} \int_K^{K+h} (s − K)\Phi(T,s)\,ds 
 - h e^{−rT} \int_{K+h}^\infty \Phi(T,s)\,ds\right) \\
 &= -\frac1h e^{−rT} \int_K^{K+h} (s − K)\Phi(T,s)\,ds 
 - e^{−rT} \int_{K+h}^\infty \Phi(T,s)\,ds.
\end{align}

Now observe that for $h > 0,$
\begin{align}
\left\lvert \int_K^{K+h} (s − K)\Phi(T,s)\,ds \right\rvert
&= \int_K^{K+h} \lvert(s − K)\Phi(T,s)\rvert\,ds \\
&\leq \int_K^{K+h} h \max_{K\leq s\leq K+h}\lvert\Phi(T,s)\rvert\,ds \\
& = h^2 \max_{K\leq s\leq K+h}\lvert\Phi(T,s)\rvert.
\end{align}
We get the same result for $h < 0$ by reversing the limits of integration.
Therefore
$$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac1h\left\lvert \int_K^{K+h} (s − K)\Phi(T,s)\,ds \right\rvert
= \lim_{h\to 0} \left( h \max_{K\leq s\leq K+h}\lvert\Phi(T,s)\rvert\right) = 0, $$

so
$$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{c(T,K+h) - c(T,K)}h
 = \lim_{h\to 0}\left(- e^{−rT} \int_{K+h}^\infty \Phi(T,s)\,ds\right)
 = - e^{−rT} \int_K^\infty \Phi(T,s)\,ds. $$